# proving integrability and equality

Tags: real-analysis

I am having trouble proving following:

Suppose $f$ is integrable on $(0, a)$. Then $g(x)=\int_{x}^{a}t^{-1}f(t)\,dt$ is integrable on $(0,a)$ and $\int_{0}^{a}g(x)\,dx=\int_{0}^{a}f(x)\,dx$.

Any hints? What kind of theorem should I use in this case? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Fubini Theorem for $A=\{(t,x): 0<x<a, x<t<a\}$ we have $$\int_0^a g(x) dx =\int_0^a \left(\int_x^a t^{-1} f(t) dt \right)dx =\iint_A t^{-1} f(t) dtdx =\int_0^a \left(\int_0^t t^{-1} f(t)dx  \right)dt =\int_0^a f(t) dt $$

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x,t)=I_{\{(x,t):t>x\}} \frac {f(t)} t$. Then $g$ is jointly measurable and integrable on $(0,a) \times (0,a)$. Apply Fubini's Theorem.

Justification for use of Fubini's Theorem:
 $\int_0^{a}\int_0^{a} I_{\{(x,t):t>x\}} |\frac {f(t)} t| dx dt=\int_0^{a}  |f(t)| dt <\infty$, so Tonelli's Theorem shows that $g$ is integrable on $(0,a) \times (0,a)$. Now apply Fubini's Theorem.